# Javascript not firing on button click

Tags: javascript, html, button, buttonclick

I have a html button that should be firing javascript on button click. It recognizes the button click and display the confirm alert but does not continue on and post the console.logs or go to into the ajax method. 
Here is the javascipt function:

```
      $('.Delete')
         .click(function() {
    return confirm("Are you sure you'd like to delete this entry?"
        if(return = true)
    {
                 var parent = $(this).parent().prev();
                 var tr = $(this).closest('tr');


                 var ValNode = tr.find(".typeText").first();
                 var AddrNode = parent.children(".AddrText").first();

                 var Val = ValNode.val();
                 var addr = addrNode.val();

                 console.log(Val);
                 console.log(addr);

                 var item = { Value: Val, Address: addr }
                 deleteItem(userID, item);
    }

         });
```

This is the html elements I think it may have to do with the relationship of the button to the elements its calling. I have them as cousins.

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" id="ListView1" >
        <LayoutTemplate>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <a href="#">Type</a>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <a href="#">Address</a>
                        </th>                                                                                    
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                   <input type="text" id="Type" class="TypeText "  value="<%# Eval("Type")%>" />                     
                   <input type="text" id="Addr" class="AddrText "  value="<%# Eval("Address")%>" />                
                </td>
                <td>
                   <input type="button" id="btn_update" class="Update" value="Update" />
                   <input type="button" id="btn_delete" class="Delete" value="Delete" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.`return` is a *reserved word* in JavaScript. It is used to specify what a function returns to the caller. Do not use it for variable names.

Change

`return confirm("Are you sure you'd like to delete this entry?"`

to

`var result = confirm("Are you sure you'd like to delete this entry?");`

2.Your `if` condition check is incorrect

Change

`if(return = true)`

to

`if(result == true)`

Answer (score 1):

`return`is a reserved keyword, which returns the execution to the function invoked current function. You need something like this:

```
var retVal = confirm("Are you sure you'd like to delete this entry?");
if (retVal) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies with `return`:

```
$('.Delete')
    .click(function() {
        var sure = confirm("Are you sure you'd like to delete this entry?");
        if (sure) {
            var parent = $(this).parent().prev();
            // ...
            // the rest
            // ...
        }
    });
```

`return` is a reserved word in JavaScript, so you should use something else.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

```
if (confirm(....))
{
}
```

Cause the "return" exit your function.